# How to deploy a React App with ASP .Net Web API on IIS?

Tags: reactjs, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, web-deployment

I have a working back-end ASP.Net Web API project in my solution. And a React Front-end App in a project created with ASP.NET Web Application template, under the same solution. I want to deploy my solution.

**How can I do that full-stack App working on IIS?**

Answer (score 1):

You can first deploy the back-end ASP.Net Web API project to IIS, and then deploy React Front-end App in the Web API project:

[image]

[image]